# Scaling: Docker containers vs Vms

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand the benefits of scaling an app via docker.

As I understand it; if I have a dockerized app running in a single docker container or pod in kubernetes; to scale it i.e. in the case of increased load I would create multiple instances of the same container and load balance requests to each container; thing is if all these containers are on the same vm aren't they all drawing from the same system resources?

What is scaling via docker then? Is it real? If all the container instances of your app are all drawing on the resources of the host machine?

Comment: you should read http://bodenr.blogspot.fr/2014/05/kvm-and-docker-lxc-benchmarking-with.html

Comment: see also https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/

Comment: Thanks. Having a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that scaling up and running more instances of a container on a single host will cause them to compete for resources. You'd want a kubernetes cluster with more than one 'minion'/host nodes. Having more than one container on a single host can be good, if load balanced properly, and a single container crashes, the other will still be up, without any delay or downtime while the replacement container is created.